# Question about changing minimizer and impact on objective value

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, proof-explanation

I have the a question about the following [proof](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Etimsears/tr.pdf), page 5 lemma 2. Suppose we want for $m$ data samples $y_i$ to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^ml(y_i-\mu)$ where $l(x)=x\tau\mathbb{1}_{x\ge 0} -x\mathbb{1}_{x\le 0}(1-\tau) $. If $\mu^*$ is a minimizer of the optimization problem above and we denote with $m_+$ the number of points where $y_i>\mu^*$. If we slightly increase the $\mu^*$ by $\delta\mu^*$ why does the objective function change according to $[(1-m_+)(1-\tau)-m_+\tau]\delta\mu^*$?

I do see that the part $-m_+\tau\delta\mu^*$ is what we "gain". However, the first part is clearly from the fact that the other points below $\mu^*$ are getting a worse value. But it could well be that some change side. So how do they come up with that expression in particular the value $(1-m_+)$?

Comment: @AlexRavsky I've edited my questions. Should have read as number of points instead of set. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained that the function change $\delta f$ equals $(m(1-\tau)-m_+)\delta\mu^*$ for sufficiently small $\delta\mu^*$ as follows. We have $\delta f=\sum_{i=1}^m l(y_i-\mu^*-\delta\mu^*)- l(y_i-\mu^*)$. We pick $\delta\mu^*$ so small that $y_i-\mu^*-\delta\mu^*$ has the same sign as $y_i-\mu^*$ for each $i$ such that $y_i-\mu^*\ne 0$. Then

$$l(y_i-\mu^*-\delta\mu^*)- l(y_i-\mu^*)=$$
$$((y_i-\mu^*-\delta\mu^*)-(y_i-\mu^*))\tau\mathbb{1}_{ y_i-\mu^*\ge 0}-
((y_i-\mu^*-\delta\mu^*)-(y_i-\mu^*))(1-\tau)\mathbb{1}_{ y_i-\mu^*\le 0}=$$
$$-\delta\mu^*\tau\mathbb{1}_{ y_i-\mu^*\ge 0}+\delta\mu^* (1-\tau)\mathbb{1}_{ y_i-\mu^*\le 0}.$$
$$-\delta\mu^*\tau+\delta\mu^*\mathbb{1}_{ y_i-\mu^*\le 0}.$$

If $y_i=\mu^*$ then anyway

$$l(y_i-\mu^*-\delta\mu^*)- l(y_i-\mu^*)=l(-\delta\mu^*)-l(0)=\delta\mu^* (1-\tau)-0
=-\delta\mu^*\tau+\delta\mu^*\mathbb{1}_{ y_i-\mu^*\le 0}.$$

Thus

$$\delta f=\sum_{i=1}^m -\delta\mu^*\tau+\delta\mu^*\mathbb{1}_{ y_i-\mu^*\le 0}=(-m\tau+(m-m_+))\delta\mu^*.$$

Comment: many thanks for your answer. So you think there proof is wrong?

Comment: @swissy Yes, if a minimizer is a point where $f$ attains its minimum. For instance, let $m=2$, $\tau=\tfrac 12$, $y_1=-\tfrac 12$, and $y_2=\tfrac 12$. Then $l(x)= \tfrac 12|x|$ and $f(\mu)= \tfrac 12 \left(\left|\tfrac 12-\mu\right|+\left|\tfrac 12+\mu\right|\right)$, that is a half of a sum of distances from $\mu$ to points $y_i$. Thus any point $\mu^*\in (y_1,y_2)$ is a minimizer of $f$ with $m_+=1$. A sufficiently small increase of $\mu^*$ does not change the value of $f(\mu^*)$.

Comment: This disagrees with the formula from the paper (which provides a decrement $\tfrac 12\delta\mu^*$), but agrees with my formula.